# PHP JavaBridge ireport - the pdf file is blank

Tags: javascript, php, pdf, php-java-bridge

I have connect the xampp-php file via JavaBridge and connect it with my .jrxml file. It can success download it as .pdf file.
However, the .pdf file is blank at all. It show nicely at my ireport file. I am using the Microsft SQL server 2008 as my database server.

```
﻿<?php 
define('JAVA_INC_URL','http://localhost:8080/JavaBridge/java/Java.inc'); 
require_once(JAVA_INC_URL);
set_time_limit(0);

 // créer une instance de la classe Java java.lang.System dans PHP
    $system = new JavaClass('java.lang.System');
    $class = new JavaClass("java.lang.Class");
    $class->forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
    $driverManager = new JavaClass("java.sql.DriverManager");
    $conn = $driverManager->getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://xxxxxx:1433","xx","xxxxxxxx");
    //compilation
    $compileManager = new   
    JavaClass("net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager");
    $viewer = new JavaClass("net.sf.jasperreports.view.JasperViewer");
    $report = $compileManager->compileReport("C:/xampp/htdocs/test report 
    jasper/2/report2.jrxml");
    // fill
    $fillManager = new JavaClass("net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager");
    $params = new Java("java.util.HashMap");
            $params->put('orderno', "SOP00014");
    $emptyDataSource = new Java("net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JREmptyDataSource");

    $runmanager = new Java("net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperRunManager");

    $jasperPrint = $fillManager->fillReport($report, $params, $conn);



$format = $_GET['format'];

switch ($format) 
{
    case 'pdf':


        $outputPath = realpath(".")."\\"."report"."\\"."export.pdf";


        $exporter= new Java("net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter");

        $exporter->setParameter(java("net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRExporterParameter")->JASPER_PRINT,$jasperPrint);
        $exporter->setParameter(java("net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRExporterParameter")->OUTPUT_FILE_NAME,$outputPath);

        header("Content-type: application/pdf");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=export.pdf");

        readfile($outputPath);
        unlink($outputPath);

        $exporter->exportReport();
        break;
    case 'csv':

        $outputPath = realpath(".")."\\"."report"."\\"."export.csv";


        $exporter= new Java("net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRCsvExporter");

        $exporter->setParameter(java("net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRExporterParameter")->JASPER_PRINT,$jasperPrint);
        $exporter->setParameter(java("net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRExporterParameter")->OUTPUT_FILE_NAME,$outputPath);

        header("Content-type: application/csv");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=export.csv");

        readfile($outputPath);
        unlink($outputPath);

        $exporter->exportReport();
        break;
    case 'txt':

        $outputPath = realpath(".")."\\"."report"."\\"."export.txt";

        $exporter= new Java("net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRTextExporter");


        $exporter->setParameter(java("net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRTextExporterParameter")->PAGE_WIDTH,120);
        $exporter->setParameter(java("net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRTextExporterParameter")->PAGE_HEIGHT,60);
        $exporter->setParameter(java("net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRExporterParameter")->JASPER_PRINT,$jasperPrint);
        $exporter->setParameter(java("net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRExporterParameter")->OUTPUT_FILE_NAME,$outputPath);

        header("Content-type: plain/text");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=export.txt");


        $exporter->exportReport();

        readfile($outputPath);
        unlink($outputPath);

        break;
    case 'pptx':
        $outputPath = realpath(".")."\\"."report"."\\"."export.pptx";                   
        $exporter= new Java("net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.ooxml.JRPptxExporter");
        $exporter->setParameter(java("net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRExporterParameter")->JASPER_PRINT,$jasperPrint);
        $exporter->setParameter(java("net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRExporterParameter")->OUTPUT_FILE_NAME,$outputPath);
        header("Content-type: aapplication/vnd.ms-powerpoint");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=export.pptx");
        $exporter->exportReport();

        readfile($outputPath);
        unlink($outputPath);
        break;
    case 'doc':
        $outputPath = realpath(".")."\\"."report"."\\"."export.docx";                   
        $exporter= new Java("net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.ooxml.JRDocxExporter");
        $exporter->setParameter(java("net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRExporterParameter")->JASPER_PRINT,$jasperPrint);
        $exporter->setParameter(java("net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRExporterParameter")->OUTPUT_FILE_NAME,$outputPath);
        header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-word");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=export.docx");
        $exporter->exportReport();

        readfile($outputPath);
        unlink($outputPath);
        break;

    default:
        # code...
        break;
}
?>
```

Comment: A PDF file is a binary file. The object structure of the PDF objects is expressed in characters that are within the range of ASCII. The content streams (images and compressed PDF syntax with page content) is stored in binary format. If you transfer or store the document using the wrong encoding (e.g. you treat it as a text file instead of as a binary file), the object structure will be preserved, but all the page content and images will be corrupted. That results in a PDF of which all pages are blank. You should find out where in your process the PDF gets corrupted by turning binary into text.

Comment: in the tomcat start.bat, It show 
no visible constructor found in net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperRunManager,returning class instead of an instance:this may be what you want.Please correct this error or please use the function java ("net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperRunManager") instead

But i have ady add the jasperreport.jar with the latest version into JavaBridge\WEB-INF\lib

Comment: AND also this error in tomcat start.bat
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlDigesterFactory). log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.